# include or call php or html file via .js

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a js file that has the code for navigation for a site with ~600 pages..
Now I want to change the menu(colors, background, links etc) and I don't want to edit the JS file as the code here is like using images for the menu..so I was thinking that I will create a php file or html file and then call it inside that js file. Is this something possible?

Please advise.

Comment: I advise you to post the relevant code

Comment: whoever downvoted this - I don't understand what is the need to downvote this question? Is this not something reasonable to ask how to handle a situation where you have so many pages coded years back and now trying to fix something? You all may be smart but doesn't mean that others shouldn't ask a question that you don't like or want or see in stackoverflow. 
moderators - if this is by done by some top users, you should check this and make a decision when to downvote and when not to..
doesn't make sense at all when I see downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the js render an iframe instead of an img and pass along the url to the php/html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between PHP, HTML and JS. They each occupy a different domain in web programming. PHP is for server side logic, HTML is a structural language and JS is an action-oriented language intended to function on top of the HTML that exists in the page (and may be rendered in JS).

All programmers have at one point tried to "hack" code like you are doing, by trying to find a band-aid fix to a complicated solution. It is not worth it. You will lose performance in the best of cases and either fail outright or lose browser compatibility and user interface quality the vast majority of the time.

In short, take your time and edit the JS. You can always do a find/replace on images to strip them out and insert CSS class declarations in their place. Do it right and you'll save yourself a big headache later on.

Comment: The "headache later on" thing is HUGE. There was a project before I got hired on where I work now, and I've basically had to recode it from the ground up piece by piece because it was ill-structured and noone had any idea what did what :/

Comment: @Alex Demchak: Same here ;) I took over a project from a beginner programmer and spent countless hours trying to decipher the spaghetti that was patched together with no attention to form or readability.

Comment: thanks for the understanding, but i hope you all will understand that sometime we don't have much control if we don't get paid for the project as freelancers. Options are limited - we have to say yes or no. I prefer not to say no, so approached Stackoveflow to see if anyone has similar experience..